# an interface object cannt be initialized in onAttach?

Tags: java, android, interface

I cretaed an interface `DataPasserInterface` to pass data from a fragment to its hosting activity. i iniitized the interface in `onAttach` as shown below in the code, the problem is, at run time, the App crashes and I receive the below posted `logCat` error.

i do not know why `this.dataPasserObj = (DataPasserInterface) activity;` causes an error? logcat says that , the interface object can not be casted?!

**interface**:

```
private DataPasserInterface dataPasserObj;
...
...
...
 public interface DataPasserInterface {

void onTopicsListChosen(ArrayList<String> chosenTopicsList);
```

}

**onAttach**:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.w(TAG, "@onAttach().");

    this.dataPasserObj = (DataPasserInterface) activity;
    this.designList = new ArrayList<ItemDesign>();
}
```

**logcat**:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(7828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(7828): Process: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02, PID: 7828
 E/AndroidRuntime(7828): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02.DataPasserInterface
 E/AndroidRuntime(7828):    at com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02.Eco_Settings_Frag.onAttach(Eco_Settings_Frag.java:95)
```

**update**

**onCreate() of the activity that hosts fragments and this activity implements the interface**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w(TAG, "@onCreate().");

    this.mqttSettingsDB = new MQTT_Settings_DB(this);
    this.sqliteDB = this.mqttSettingsDB.getWritableDatabase();

    if (this.fragList == null) {
        this.fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        this.fragList.add(new MQTT_Settings_Frag());
        this.fragList.add(new Eco_Settings_Frag());
        this.fragList.add(new Logger_Settings_Frag());
    }

    initviews(R.layout.settings_activity);
    setUpActionBar();
    this.viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerListener);
}
```

Comment: yes it can, but your activity must implement the interface you are casting to, otherwise you will get a ClassCastException

Comment: Just curious why you are doing this action in onAttach rather than in onCreate?

Comment: @michaelkagan i think because it is just an initialisation indpendent whther or not the view is created

Comment: @michaelkagan: why you are not using constructor of class in which `onAttach` have for getting `DataPasserInterface` object from `SettingsActivity`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K  i thinsk i did not understand your point. for clarification, i am initialising the interface in the fragment and the main activity will implement it

Comment: @rmaik: How you are adding Fragment to ListActivity? please show code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ok, i posted the code , please see the update section

Comment: you get the activity instance, Yes! but not proper to handle casting after super.onAttach(activity);, try calling super at the end of the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ClassCastException: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02.SettingsActivity

Probably not implementing `DataPasserInterface` interface in `SettingsActivity`

Suggestion Create constructor in `Eco_Settings_Frag` class for getting `DataPasserInterface` interface and initializing other values :

```
public Eco_Settings_Frag(Activity activity){
    this.dataPasserObj = (DataPasserInterface) activity;
    this.designList = new ArrayList<ItemDesign>();
}
```

and pass `SettingsActivity` context when creating object of `Eco_Settings_Frag` class :

```
 .....
 this.fragList.add(new Eco_Settings_Frag(SettingsActivity.this));
 this.fragList.add(new Logger_Settings_Frag());
 .....
```

Also implement `DataPasserInterface` interface in `SettingsActivity` Activity

Comment: ok fine, but why should i pass a reference to the contxt of the mainactivity to the Eco-fragment?

Comment: @rmaik: This is custom event listener pattern so you need to use same class object in which you are implementing `DataPasserInterface` for notifying call by calling `dataPasserObj.onTopicsListChosen(designList)` from fragment